# Firebase login using username (not email)

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i got this code from someone, but i dont really understand how it works. especially for UsersBean usersBean. Any help? Thank you.

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(txvUsername.getText().toString().trim());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0

            for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // do something with the individual "issues"
                UsersBean usersBean = user.getValue(UsersBean.class);

                if (usersBean.password.equals(txvPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you are querying the firebase database on the node "users" and comparing your textView value with the saved email in the database.
After this , you are adding SingleValueEventListener on your query which works asynchronously and you will get the callback from the firebase in onDataChange() function which will give you the object of DataSnapshot and you can get the value from this object like dataSnapshot.getValue()

In your code, you are getting all the children of your users node from datasnapshot and you put them in a loop to match the user's password with your txvPassword field.

UserBean is the POJO or model class which contains the fields like 
password, email etc.And you are converting the value of the dataSnapshot to the UserBean class so that you can easily save all the details of the user at one time like this:-

UsersBean usersBean = user.getValue(UsersBean.class);

and you can use all the values of the UserBean class to write the furthur logic.
I hope you understand now.If have any other query, you can ask !!

Comment: still have problem for usersBeans. it returns "cannot resolve symboll from 'UsersBeans'. should i create new class for it ? thank u

Comment: first see the fields of the users table in your firebase console and then create this class with all those fields with same name..Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database stores data as JSON. From what I can see, your code works with a database that looks (at least) like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "email": "user1@domain.com",
      "password": "passwordforuser1"
    },
    "userid2": {
      "email": "user2@domain.com",
      "password": "passwordforuserid2"
    }
  }
}
```

Each user from this structure is represented by a `UsersBean` object in the app. The `UsersBean` class is custom-made for the JSON structure of your database, and has a single public field or property for each property in the JSON for each user.

The simplest `UsersBean` for the above JSON would look like:

```
public class UsersBean {
  public String email;
  public String password;
}
```

So here we represent each JSON property with a public field with the (exact) same name. If you do that, the Firebase client can read the properties from a `DataSnapshot` into the corresponding `UsersBean` with:

```
UsersBean usersBean = user.getValue(UsersBean.class);
```

Since you got the code from someone, you should probably ask that person to also give you their `UsersBean` class (and other bean classes). While these are typically not hard to create, there's no sense duplicating the work.